# using array_intersect

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, array-intersect

I have 2 tables.
One with a list of businesses and their addresses
the other with a list of zip codes and their longitude and latitude.
I have a form that accepts a zip code and a number of miles to check radius.

all the radius stuff works from a script i found online.
what I need is to echo the entries of businesses that are within the radius.

So far i have 2 queries. 
one gets all entries zip codes inside the db
the other get all zipcodes within the range i put in the form

i'm using array_intersect to find the matching ones.
my problem is it only returns the first entry found.
I'm SURE i need a while loop to do this but i have no idea how to do it.

code snippet:

```
     $insideRadius = array_intersect($data, $zipArray);
```

The $data is all the zip codes from the business table.
the $zip array is all the zip codes within range.

Comment: I might be missing something but if you only have coordinates for the zip codes (and not the businesses and addresses) how are you going to find out which ones are within x miles of ... wherever

Comment: the table with long and lat also have the zip code. sorry if i didn't say that

Comment: so you basicaly want to `JOIN` them on zip code ?

Comment: well that worked but it only gave me 1 entry still

Comment: yes i guess i need them to join on zip code... there was just a comment here and it worked "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE zip in (".implode(",",$zipArray) . ")";

Comment: yes that would work if you have the $zipArray and want the entries within those zip codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just select the businesses that have a zipcode listed in the $zipArray?

`"SELECT * FROM business WHERE zipcode IN (" . implode(",", $zipArray) . ")"`

In PHP you could run it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM business WHERE zipcode IN (" . implode(",", $zipArray) . ")");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row["name"] . "<br />";
    echo $row["zipcode"] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked but it only gave me 1 entry back i have 2 entries in my table. 2 zipcodes that are within 5 miles of each other and only the first one that the query matches is displayed.

Comment: If you execute this query, you must loop through the results. You can only fetch one row in each iteration. Can you try this query, and if it doesn't work, post your PHP code that executes the query and loops throug the results.

Comment: try running it manualy from some MySQL client (like `SELECT * FROM business WHERE zipcode IN (100,200,300)`)  to check if the problem is in the query or somewhere in your php code.

Comment: @DevinPrejean: you mean the $zipArray? Can you add the output of the `print_r($zipArray)` to your question?

Comment: i ran it manually and it still only pulls the first one. i do need a while loop i'm sure. i need to go figure that out i don't want to sound like a total noob but i forget things fast if i haven't done them in a while. i have been writing php code for a year or so now.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. that was it. I NEVER would have figured out the implode thing. i've never ever used that nor do i know what it actually does

Comment: well: it converts an array into a string, by taking each element and separating it with the given separator, in this case: a comma. You also have explode which does exactly the opposite: converts a string into an array, splitting the string on the given separator...

Comment: Thats awesome! thanks so much for the quick lesson. I'll be using that more often its so much simpler and less code